# Adding external folder jar in to build path

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, buildpath

In my RCP plugin application, earlier having a folder at project level "neededJar" in which i have all external jar needed in project build

But now I want to put all jar at a common library say a lib folder in installation directory, at my workspace i added needed jar as project->build path->configure build path->add external jar it works but when I export the plugin project it is not able to resolve dependency.

I also tried to give it as class path variable but it did not work.

My classpath entry is as follow:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="MY_JAR"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="MY_JAR/MYClasses.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="MY_JAR/jMYlex.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="MY_JAR/MYsm.jar"/>
```

By digging i got to know, not sure about it I am missing some entry in Manifiest.MF and build properties.

Please count what are the steps that i am missing. Please suggest me through process to add external jar in plugin project

update: it is yet not answered well.

Comment: removed. Misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a linked folder. 
Create a new folder in your workspace, but open the "advanced" tab in the wizard. Chose "Link to alternate location".

Just be careful with references to folders outside your workspace, since they have a tendency to move from time to time :).

Comment: just take scenerio I will put the jar on the lib folder at the time of installation. I want to referenced that from my workspace too. at workspace it is fine but when i export the plugin for testing it tells error. please put a step process to achieve it. It leads me what the entry i am missing inmanifiest.mf and build.properties.

Comment: Here is a step-by-step guide: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm and an explaination of the linked resources: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_linked.htm   . When building, you will have to check the folder in the build.properties file like you do with all your other folders.